# How to organize constants depending on a run time value?

Tags: java, oop, constants

I use constants in my code and put them as static members into the classes they belong to (header size into the packet class, etc.).

Now I run into the problem, that one central constant, that determines many others is actually dependent on a value I only get at startup.

Imagine the packets always having the same header length, but that header length depends on the amount of servers it travels through.

That amount stays constant over the time of the program, but is not known beforehand, of course.

It seems I should have a constants class which calculates the constants, when the value is known at startup, but that would rip them out of all the relevant classes.

Comment: You can define your constants as calculations based on runtime arguments, no? For example: `private static final int HEADER_SIZE = Main.args[0] * 256;`

Answer (score 0):

> but that would rip them out of all the relevant classes

You can have a singleton with your "fundamental" constants that you get on startup and then put logic that calculates header length and other derived constants into their relevant classes.

Comment: When would that logic be called? In the constructor?

Comment: I would put it into static methods. Maybe calculate the value the first time that static method is called and put the value into a static field, and then just return the value of that field on subsequent calls

Comment: So static getters, instead of constants?